# LINQ to SQL (insert into fact table based on 3 tables)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, left-join

I am not able to work with the below join.
Idea is to find any new (AumProductId and IdClient) combinations from AceBiMonthlyDaos to create entry in Investment table with Unique Id, if those AumProductId and IdClient exist in Reference table of Instrument and Financial Account respectively.

```
var result = (from AceBi in context.AceBiMonthlyDaos
                  join Inst in context.Instruments 
                      on AceBi.AumProductId equals Inst.AceId 
                  join FinAcct in context.FinancialAccounts 
                      on AceBi.IdClient equals FinAcct.AceClientId
                  join Invst in context.Investments 
                      on new { Inst.Id, FinAcct.Id } equals { Invst.InstrumentId, Invst.FinaAcctId} into pair                                       
                      from InvestmentDao in pair.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: I've only been working with LINQ to SQL for a few weeks now so if I'm incorrect I hope someone corrects me, but without knowing the associated values in each table I can't recommend specifically how to join or where.  From my short experience it SEEMS to me that the code above fails on the 2nd attempt to join a table onto the AceBi instance.  However after some tests I found that you can join FinAcct to Inst.  It would help if you could clarify exactly the corresponding sql joins you are trying to perform and provide the corresponding columns of each table you are trying to join.

Comment: The below query worked. Thanks. 

var query = (from AceBi in context.AceBiMonthlyDaos
join Inst in context.Instruments on AceBi.AumProductId equals Inst.AceId
join FinAcct in context.FinancialAccounts on AceBi.IdClient equals FinAcct.AceClientId
                             join Invst in context.Investments on new { instrumentId = Inst.Id, finAccountId = FinAcct.Id } equals new { instrumentId = Invst.InstrumentId, finAccountId = Invst.FinAcctId }
into pair
from Invst in pair.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new { Inst, FinAcct, Invst }).Distinct();

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from AceBi in context.AceBiMonthlyDaos
                         join Inst in context.Instruments on AceBi.AumProductId equals Inst.AceId
                         join FinAcct in context.FinancialAccounts on AceBi.IdClient equals FinAcct.AceClientId
                         join Invst in context.Investments on new { instrumentId = Inst.Id, finAccountId = FinAcct.Id } equals new { instrumentId = Invst.InstrumentId, finAccountId = Invst.FinAcctId }
                         into pair
                         from Invst in pair.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new { Inst, FinAcct, Invst }).Distinct();
```